# Gdal overview creation

Tags: gdal, cache

I need to generate gdal overview for tif image having parameter value 2 4.but when I run following error shows-
 Error 4:'example.tif.ovr' not recognized as a supported file format. overviews building failed. 
please suggest guys with example are also welcome.

Comment: Improve your old question rather than repeat it. What's wrong with the examples in http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html?